Adjusting styling for p-avatarGroup in primeNG
I use primeNG in my application and use, among other things, the p-avatarGroup component. I would like to customize the styling of this component, especially the margin between avatars. Currently the margin is set to 1rem, but I want to change it to -0.5rem. I tried to achieve this with the following CSS:
.p-avatar-group p-avatar + p-avatar {
  margin-left: -0.5rem !important;
}


However, this doesn't seem to work. Is there another way to successfully adjust the margin? I would also be grateful for general tips on how to customize the styles of various primeNG components.
